# How to access multiple FormGroups in an Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular

Is there a way in Angular Reactive to get on the parent component a list of all FormGroups ? It seems if i set a custom component which creates a new FormGroup in its component it does not show up on the parent. So i am wondering if and where there is a place to get access in parent of all form groups either setup directly on parent or on child.

Comment: You probably want to have a service hold an array of form groups, and then you can refer to that service property in the parent and child components. To get a good answer here, you should post your code and give more detail about what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but what you could do is create a FormGroup in the parent nesting a set of FormGroups for each child component, and passing the corresponding FormGroup through an input to the child. 
In the child you can assign that FormGroup to a form HTML element and treat it as a standalone form; all of the changes in that FormGroup will also be reflected in the parent FormGroup in the parent component.

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}
...
this.myForm = fb.group({
  child0: this.fb.group({
    ...
  })
  child1: this.fb.group({
    ...
  })
});
```

Then you would pass `this.myForm.get('child0')` to the first child and so on.